# Java Checking the type of object in a container

Tags: java, arraylist

In java, if an object in an ArrayList is of type double. What method checks and returns a boolean value to tell me if the object is of a specific dynamic type?

Something like this:

```
  pseudo code:
         if(bid.get(i) is double )
              {

               return bid.get(i);
              }
```

Comment: `bid.get(i) instanceof Double`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList` can hold `Double`s, but not `double`s (Java Collections can't hold primitive types directly).

You can write :

```
if (bid.get(i) instanceof  Double)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (bid.get(i) instanceof Double) {
    return bid.get(i);
}
```

Note this will only work for object types, so you can check for `Double`s (i.e., `java.lang.Double` instances), but not for primitive `double`s. Then again, when you add a `double` to a `List` it's autoboxed to a `Double`, so I'm guessing this distinction isn't really important to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 5 OR higher version. You can use generics and declare your arraylist as `ArrayList<Double>`, it will ensure that it only contains Double references and will prevent you from explicit type casting.
But if you have any constraint then you can use `instanceOf` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
if (bid.get(i) instanceof Double) {
    return bid.get(i);
}
```